# ui-router - loading template and childview at the using the same route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to ui-router and I was hoping that some one could assist me with essentially loading 2 views a from the one route. I was looking at the sample [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7FD5Wf?p=preview) and I was trying to get it to load the child views at the same time as the route but I could not get [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/C16THWdzO1xJ6VwVzOu6?p=preview) to work. I thought that by creating an abstract route and then calling state.go in the child route it would work but I missing something.

Any ideas appreciated.

```
        controller: function($scope){
            $state.go('route1.list');
            $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get precisely points out the issue, you've defined `route1` to be abstract and that's fine, but you can't go a to an abstract state, abstract states are only run when you navigate to a child state of that abstract state, so you must go to a child state, so change ui-sref="route1" to `ui-sref="rout1.list"`:

`<li><a ui-sref="route1.list">Route 1</a></li>`

and also inject $state into `route1.list`'s controller:

```
.state('route1.list', {
              url: "/list",
              templateUrl: "route1.list.html", //child view
              controller: function($scope,$state){
                $state.go('route1.list');
                $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
              }
          })
```

[See working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yB9goQ1LRtBwljJxMHTw?p=preview).

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, thanks for the answer. How can I make this route load and appear on page load? Do I need to use the onEnter callback or do I put it in the .run section of the config?